# new google nocaptcha popup

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

Im having some difficulties implementing the new nocaptcha from google.
What Im trying to do is use it in a popup but for some reason it appears on the page even tho I hide the element.

Here is a code snippet.

```
<script>
$('#btnMe').click(function() {
    $('.g-recaptcha').show();

});
$('.g-recaptcha').hide();
</script>

<div id="human-check">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='my public key'></div>
</div>
```

First place would be to resize the frame yet I cant find any info on how to do it with the new I'm not a Robot captcha.

Anyone had any success with this yet?

Comment: Why not show/hide #human-check ?

Comment: I have tried that too, I also tried injecting the script and div into human-check on click. The captcha somehow always stays on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose jquery in

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

So your code will be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnMe').click(function() {
    $('.g-recaptcha').show();

});
$('.g-recaptcha').hide();
}); 
</script>
```